# How to list which posts did I review "wrongly"?

Tags: feature-request, review

I want to know when the review consensus was different than the one I voted for. For simplicity, I'd call that situation that "I was wrong".

**This has nothing to do with audits, I am talking about real reviews.**

Right now I click through all items in Actions>Reviews. But that has two flaws:

- I need to check every review, not just those where I was "wrong"
- I need to check multiple times because it takes time for the review to be closed

It would be extremely useful for me to see the results but clicking through all reviews is very tedious. Is there a way? I mark this a feature request because I think there is not.